# how to put pcl file with correct name to win spooler

Tags: printing, printer-control-language, spooler

When I copy a pcl file to a windows spooler, I can't set the name and number of pages for this file in spooler. I do it from the commandline with a simple copy

```
copy file.pcl printer
```

How to copy the file to see it's name and nbr of pages in the spooler?
Can JAVA help doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Copying a file to the printer will not get you the number of pages as the spooler will not know anything about the content of the file. Under normal operation when a job is printed calls are made to the StartPagePrinter api call via the GDI subsystem, this is how the spooler knows how many pages there are in a document, but this does not occur when you use the copy function.

If you know the number of pages that the PCL document is then you could look at using the SetJob spooler API function to set the TotalPages count as appropriate. Adding a job to the spooler this way would require the following API calls to be made:

1. OpenPrinter
2. AddJob
3. SetJob
4. ScheduleJob
5. ClosePrinter

Comment: Not sure if this used to be supported, but it's not anymore.  Per MSDN, TotalPages is among the ignored members for SetJob.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162978.aspx.